# Can I hatch a Pokemon egg by riding a bike

Tags: pokemon-go

Does Pokemon Go detect and care whether you are riding a bike (or driving a car, for that matter) when hatching an egg, or do you have to be on foot?

Comment: Take a look at this blog that I wrote for getting distance while you drive. http://davismj.me/blog/pg-stay-awake/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hatch an egg, as long as you're under 20mph. So walking, cycling, or even driving slowly counts towards hatching the egg.

It isn't calculated by the pedometer, but by the distance traveled by GPS. So examples such as hanging a phone from a ceiling fan work too.

Comment: Do you have ANY evidence to support the numbers. There has been research done over at reddit, as well as many different answers here at arqade and all seam to quote different digits. My personal experience says its around OR less than 15 mph

Comment: This is just from personal experience, and from what other people have been saying. Niantic haven't released any information regarding the actual figures.

Comment: this info might be outdated, i rode my bike to work today, 12Kms at an avg speed of 20km/h (top being 24/25). Thats far below 20milesph and should be within 15mph. i only gained 1km out of the 12.